# `.DS_Store N` files appearing on Desktop in macOS Catalina

Tags: beta, catalina

I am using macOS Catalina 10.15 Beta (19A501i)

My desktop is becoming cluttered with hidden files:

```
pi@πPro ~/Desktop
> ls -la
total 240
drwxr-xr-x@  3 pi  staff    96 13 Sep  2018 $RECYCLE.BIN
drwx------@ 19 pi  staff   608 15 Jul 07:18 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 16 pi  staff   512 14 Jul 01:35 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 pi  staff  8196 14 Jul 22:58 .DS_Store 15
-rw-r--r--@  1 pi  staff  8196 13 Jul 15:11 .DS_Store 2
-rw-r--r--@  1 pi  staff  8196 13 Jul 15:32 .DS_Store 3
-rw-r--r--@  1 pi  staff  6148 14 Jul 22:58 .DS_Store 4
-rw-r--r--@  1 pi  staff  8196 15 Jul 06:33 .DS_Store 5
-rw-r--r--@  1 pi  staff  8196 15 Jul 06:34 .DS_Store 6
-rw-r--r--@  1 pi  staff  6148 13 Jul 17:12 .DS_Store 7
-rw-r--r--@  1 pi  staff  8196 15 Jul 06:53 .DS_Store 8
-rw-r--r--@  1 pi  staff  8196 15 Jul 07:00 .DS_Store 9
```

Many of these files don't even show up on the Desktop.

Is this likely to be some beta issue?

Comment: Is your question about what are .DS_Store files or is it why they're showing up on your desktop?

Comment: As it is a beta there will be problems/issues. Your best bet is to file feedback using the feedback assistant.app and wait for the next version to come out

Comment: Files starting with a dot don't show in Finder windows unless you use `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES; killall Finder` . Do these files show in your Finder?